# Tmux link-pane with format variables

Tags: linux, debian, tmux

I am trying to link a window from another session by specifying target session using format variable. In that way I hope to get it always linked next to the current active window.

The hard coded version of the working command:

```
:link-window -a -s 1:remote -t 0:2
```

in which case I specify a target pane literaly. When I try any of:

```
:link-window -a -s 1:remote -F -t "#{session_name}":"#{window_index}"
:link-window -a -s 1:remote -F "#{session_name}":"#{window_index}"
:link-window -a -s 1:remote -t "#{session_name}":"#{window_index}"
```

I got an error. The notable part here is that when I **do** use `-F` flag, the usage for `link-window` command is displayed. And when I omit it and use only `-t`, the error is `cann't find window #{session_name}`

Does it mean that `link-window` command simply doesn't support format variables?

Answer (score 1):

-t does not support format variables and link-window does not support -F. run-shell will expand so you can do it by doing, for example:

```
run "tmux linkw -t '#{session_name}'"
```